# PosgtreSQL — Is it possible to specify a sequence name in a GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY column?

Tags: postgresql, php, sequence, identity

When using PHP’s `lastInsertId()` method with PostgreSQL, it’s necessary to know the name of the sequence.

If I defined the column using `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`, I know I can get the sequence name using something like `pg_get_serial_sequence('whatever', 'id')`.

Is it possible to specify a sequence name in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to specify the sequence name when you create an identity column. PostgreSQL chooses the name automatically as `<tablename>_<columnname>_seq`. If there is already a relation of that name, it tries `<tablename>_<columnname>_seq1` and so on until it finds a free name.

If you don't want to rely on the automatically chosen name, you can find the name of the sequence with `pg_get_serial_sequence()` and use `ALTER SEQUENCE ... RENAME TO ...` to rename it after the fact. That won't break anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Supplementary question: do you know whether it’s possible to combine `ALTER SEQUENCE` with `pg_get_serial_sequence()`? I’ve tried and failed.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: That’s what I thought. The default pattern name looks reliable though. I only need it for PHP so I can do it that way. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Manngo: Don't blindly rely on the default. Query the seq name, and use it in the next step.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter No, I used PHP to fetch the current sequence name and then rename it. In fact, PHP requires the sequence name for its `lastInsertId()` method, so renaming it isn’t important. I just wanted to see how far I could automate the process in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the sequence name when you create an identity column:

```
create table my_table (id bigint primary key generated by default as identity (sequence name my_seq));
```

and then check the sequence name:

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'id');
```

| pg_get_serial_sequence |
| --- |
| public.my_seq |